# recursively split script in R by balanced brackets

Tags: r, regex

Is there a way to split any R script into a nested list according to balanced brackets (with control for depth of nesting)

ie

```
function(x){
x_identity=sapply(x, function(i) i*2)

x_squared=sapply(x, function(i){
                                                   i^2
                                                   }
                            )
}
```

would return a nested list of containing two sublists that have self contained parts to could be fully evaluated.

there is [a way](https://regex101.com/r/lF0fI1/1) in pcre (php) grep to do this but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in R.

Comment: This probably can't be done in R with regex. It requires _recursion_ capability (or balanced groups) that is in Perl, PCRE, or Dot-Net. Even if using recursion, you have 2 recursive elements `({`. This is _not_ for the feint of heart, as this requires not only recursive regex, but a recursive language function to extract nested content. I've done this many times. I would charge money to do it for someone else. Try to do it with a decent parser instead.

Comment: how does perl do that? R regex can run perl commands

Comment: parse to turn strings into expression; quote and bquote to eval a parsed expression; and environments to control values of variables. Strsplit or stringr library handle split and transform script file to r strings.

Comment: do you mean to use quote and bquote manually?

Comment: Sorry, read your question better now. Seems like you need actual R syntax aware parsing to do this and not simply split a file to chunks at marks. I would try and see if walkAST on GitHub or pryr (e.g. walk_tree) can be of help.

Comment: The way Perl does recursion, something simple like `(\((?:(?>[^(){}]+)|(?1))*\)|\{(?:(?>[^(){}]+)|(?1))*\})`. Recursion in regex effectively matches the outer nest. You'd need a recursive function to then parse each successive core, until you reach the absolute inner core. Like this `(?xis-)(?:(?|([a-z]\w*)\s*\(|(\())((?&core)|)\)|((?&operators))|((?&content))|(.))(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>(?&operators)|(?&content)|(?:[a-z]\w*\s*\(|\()(?:(?=.)(?&core)|)\))+)(?<operators>(?>[?|]))(?<content>(?>(?![a-z]\w*\s*\(|[()]).)+))` which is probably more than you can handle.

Comment: You can't do it with balanced group or regex above because not all function bodies have a bracket. I think they will miss the nested function body in your first sapply.

Comment: There is `parse(text = x) `

Comment: how do you split the parsed text to separate function calls within it?

Comment: Can you manually construct your expected output and `dput()` it in your question?

Comment: @yonicd: You seem to forget that base  R supports PCRE regex, and what you posted at regex101 is perfectly valid to use in R. However, you cannot use a regex to split *any R script into a nested list according to balanced brackets*, because you may have unbalanced number of brackets in the string, and still it be a valid script (string literals, comments, e.g., may contain brackets).

Comment: Can you give an example of running pcre in R?

Comment: Well, I think your question is about some arbitrary code parsing. It won't help you anyway. Or edit the question.

Comment: I don't see how to call pcre in r regex only perl

Comment: You thought `perl=TRUE` enables Perl? No, it makes R use PCRE engine.

Comment: Must have been confused by the word 'perl'

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Perl or PCRE, you can use this to start out with

`((\w*)\s*\(((?:(?>[^(){}]+)|(?1))*)\)|\{((?:(?>[^(){}]+)|(?1))*)\})`

https://regex101.com/r/F1zkKe/1

Like I said, you'd only be able to get the *outer* nest per match.

The way it works is to make a recursive language function that parses
the outer form.
Inside that function, you'd call the same function to parse each inner content
(ie. *core*).

pseudo code

```
function parse( core )
{
     if ( core =~ /regex/ )
     {
          // store the outer info
          if ( group2 matched )
          {
               // store group2 function name
               // then recurse the function core
               parse( group3 );
          }
          else
          if ( group4 matched )
          {
               // store info about the beginning of a block
               // then recurse the block core
               parse( group4 );
          }
          else
          if ( groupX matched )
               // Content
          else
               // Error, unwind
               return FALSE;
     }
     return TRUE;
}
```

There is more to it of course, like the content and error handling.
The stuff that is neither a function start nor a block start.
Or, errors that are induced by non-balanced text.

This requires extra alternation's within the regex.
If doing content and errors though, the regex should be more structure than the one used here.

It's essential to know that within a *core* everything must be accounted for.
This includes content and errors.

I could do it, but it would take some extra effort I don't have time for.

This should get you started though.

Regex explained

```
 (                             # (1 start), Recursion group
      ( \w* )                       # (2), Function name, optional
      \s* 
      \(                            # (
      (                             # (3 start), Function core
           (?:
                (?> [^(){}]+ )         # Not anything that starts recursion
             |  (?1)                   # or, recurse a core
           )*
      )                             # (3 end)
      \)                            # )
   |                              # or,
      \{                            # {
      (                             # (4 start), Block core
           (?:
                (?> [^(){}]+ )         # Not anything that starts recursion
             |  (?1)                   # or, recurse a core
           )*
      )                             # (4 end)
      \}                            # }
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Comment: Will you be able to evaluate the function if it accesses anything in enclosing file scope?

Comment: @LoveTätting - Probably, if you evaluate the entire block. Not globals though. https://regex101.com/r/F1zkKe/2 here you can see what the results would be if by _parsing the core_ at each level, as described in the above pseudo above. I just moved the functions _out_ of the main block. Yeah, so you can evaluate at any level, just use the capture group text that you need.

Comment: @LoveTätting - You can always store text of functions as then are parsed, then later put it together in a string to run eval on ? Also see this https://regex101.com/r/F1zkKe/3

Comment: As mentioned above, you can flesh this regex and code out to access all content and parameters as well. I didn't do it though. It's a little tedious, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can do most of it with base R. You really should not use a regex for this if you want to evaluate the function. You will need to write a complete R parser.

#### Consider the following

R script file

```
any syntactical element of the R language

anyfunction = function(args){

  access any symbol constructed from any of the outer syntactical elements
  in enclosing scope and calculate something

  return result
}
```

To write a regex to capture the function will do you nothing if the function accesses anything outside the function in the file. You will need to match that as well, and evaluate it with R before evaluating the function. A home written R parser, that is.

#### ~/test.R

This is an example file of code to parse

```
v = c(1,2,3)
d = 1

increment = function(v, d) {
  sapply(v, function(v) v+d)

}

decrement = function(v, d) {
  increment(v,d)
  v-2*d
  increment2 = function(v, d) {
    v+d
  }
}
closure = function(){
  d
}
```

#### Parser function

This is the code to do the parsing of functions from the testfile. It parses the expressions from the testfile to an envrionment to not cloud your namespace, then evaluates them and check which mode each expression is. Then each function is put in a list and can be called by name or index. It will handle closures correctly as showed, which a regex approach would not.

It only uses base R and thus will be stable to any update in R that doesn't remove these functions from base and will handle eventual syntactical constructs such as infix declared functions.

Why write a regex parser when you can use R for the parsing of itself?

```
env = new.env()
#to not pollute namespace

src.expression = parse(file='~/test.R')
#get expressions

eval(src.expression, envir = env)
#move expressions in to environment

src.modes = sapply(ls(env), function(exp) {
  mode(get(exp, envir = env))
  }
)

funs.idx = grepl("function", src.modes)

funs.names = names(src.modes[funs.idx])
funs = lapply(funs.names, function(fun) {
  get(fun, envir = env)
}
)
names(funs) = funs.names

funs[[2]](v=c(1,2,3), 1) == funs[["increment"]](v=c(1,2,3), 1)
#TRUE TRUE TRUE

funs$closure() == 1
#TRUE
```

Unfortunately I have not solved how to do it recursively. One will have to capture the enclosing top level variables and the other variables in each function and evaluate the nested functions in that environment to keep behaviour of standard R. Although, enclosed functions are often there for the reason of only being used by its enclosing function, but one can have their reason for this I guess. I have not found a good way to parse out a nested function and save the variables from a function to an environment. For what it's worth, I hope this helps your purpose.

Comment: thank you for the example. can you paste the script of the file you are sourcing?

Comment: that makes sense. one note the lhs of `funs[[2]](v=c(1,2,3), 1) == funs[["increment"]](v=c(1,2,3), 1)` doesnt return anything so the logical doesnt evaluate

Comment: I tried it again and I tried it on codinggrounds online R parser. It works there? It really shouldn't be a matter of different R-versions and platform. Are you sure you pasted everything correctly? What exact error do you get? Both the lhs and rhs is a numeric vector that is element by element the same so you should get a logical vector in return. Could you please take a second look to see that it looks exactly the same as written? Of course, the filename need to be applied manually.

Comment: Yes. But to get it to work recursively is a challenge. I am trying to use as.list(body(.)). As a better way of achieving my goal